# How to implement Functor[Dataset]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-cats, scala-implicits, apache-spark-encoders

I am struggling on how to create an instance of `Functor[Dataset]`... the problem is that when you `map` from `A` to `B` the `Encoder[B]` must be in the implicit scope but I am not sure how to do it.

```
implicit val datasetFunctor: Functor[Dataset] = new Functor[Dataset] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Dataset[A])(f: A => B): Dataset[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
```

Of course this code is throwing a compilation error since `Encoder[B]` is not available but I can't add `Encoder[B]` as an implicit parameter because it would change the map method signature, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot apply `f` right away, because you are missing the `Encoder`. The only obvious direct solution would be: take `cats` and re-implement all the interfaces, adding an implict `Encoder` argument. I don't see any way to implement a `Functor` for `Dataset` *directly*.

**However** maybe the following substitute solution is good enough.
What you could do is to create a wrapper for the dataset, which has a `map` method without the implicit `Encoder`, but additionally has a method `toDataset`, which needs the `Encoder` in the very end.

For this wrapper, you could apply a construction which is very similar to the so-called `Coyoneda`-construction (or `Coyo`? What do they call it today? I don't know...). It essentially is a way to implement a "free functor" for an arbitrary type constructor.

Here is a sketch (it compiles with cats 1.0.1, replaced `Spark` traits by dummies):

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import cats.Functor

/** Dummy for spark-Encoder */
trait Encoder[X]

/** Dummy for spark-Dataset */
trait Dataset[X] {
  def map[Y](f: X => Y)(implicit enc: Encoder[Y]): Dataset[Y]
}

/** Coyoneda-esque wrapper for `Dataset` 
  * that simply stashes all arguments to `map` away
  * until a concrete `Encoder` is supplied during the
  * application of `toDataset`.
  *
  * Essentially: the wrapped original dataset + concatenated
  * list of functions which have been passed to `map`.
  */
abstract class MappedDataset[X] private () { self =>
  type B
  val base: Dataset[B]
  val path: B => X
  def toDataset(implicit enc: Encoder[X]): Dataset[X] = base map path

  def map[Y](f: X => Y): MappedDataset[Y] = new MappedDataset[Y] {
    type B = self.B
    val base = self.base
    val path: B => Y = f compose self.path
  }
}

object MappedDataset {
  /** Constructor for MappedDatasets.
    * 
    * Wraps a `Dataset` into a `MappedDataset` 
    */
  def apply[X](ds: Dataset[X]): MappedDataset[X] = new MappedDataset[X] {
    type B = X
    val base = ds
    val path = identity
  }

}        

object MappedDatasetFunctor extends Functor[MappedDataset] {
  /** Functorial `map` */
  def map[A, B](da: MappedDataset[A])(f: A => B): MappedDataset[B] = da map f
}
```

Now you can wrap a dataset `ds` into a `MappedDataset(ds)`, then `map` it using the implicit `MappedDatasetFunctor` as long as you want, and then call `toDataset` in the very end, there you can supply a concrete `Encoder` for the final result.

Note that this will combine all functions inside `map` into a single spark stage: it won't be able to save the intermediate results, because the `Encoder`s for all intermediate steps are missing.

---

I'm not quite there yet with studying `cats`, I cannot guarantee that this is the most idiomatic solution. Probably there is something `Coyoneda`-esque already in the library.

**EDIT:** There is [Coyoneda](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Coyoneda.scala) in the cats library, but it requires a natural transformation `F ~> G` to a functor `G`. Unfortunately, we don't have a `Functor` for `Dataset` (that was the problem in the first place). What my implementation above does is: instead of a `Functor[G]`, it requires a *single morphism* of the (non-existent) natural transformation at a fixed `X` (this is what the `Encoder[X]` is).

Comment: thank you, I am going to investigate more about Coyoneda, it seems to be the cleanest solution, right?

Comment: @Mikel: This seems to be the go-to solution if you want to build a `Functor` instance for an `F[A]` which *"cannot `map` right away, but can `map` later"*. There is also a dual Yoneda-construction for building `Functor` for `F[A]`s which *"can `map` initially, but lose this capability later on"*. I'm pretty sure that this is standard, I swear I saw it in Bjarnason/Chiusano's book, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @Mikel: Here is the original `Coyoneda` from the `cats` library: [Coyoneda.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Coyoneda.scala). I don't see immediately how you could use it directly, because it requires an `F ~> G` to a `G` with a functor, but again, you don't have a `Functor`, you have a single `Encoder[X]` for a fixed type `X`. I added a comment on that.

Comment: @Mikel Added an `edit` about why it could be that this thing is not exactly the full-blown Coyoneda, but rather a `Coyoneda` which works with a single morphism of a natural transformation, instead of the entire natural transformation (which would be a family of functions which could encode *all the `X`* at once).