# How to combine type parameter bounds and functors using Cats?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, type-parameter, scala-cats

I am encountering a number of use cases where I am end of attempting to write `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, etc instances in contexts where I am also using type parameter bounds.

For example...

```
import cats._

trait Preference[A] extends Order[A]

trait SocialWelfareFunction[-CC <: Iterable[P], +P <: Preference[_]]
  extends (CC => P)


object SocialWelfareFunction {

  def functor: Functor[({ type F[P <: Preference[_]] = SocialWelfareFunction[Iterable[P], P] })#F] = {
    ???
  }
```

...when I try to compile this I will get the following error.

```
kinds of the type arguments ([P <: Playground.this.Preference[_]]Playground.this.SocialWelfareFunction[Iterable[P],P]) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F) in trait Monad.
[P <: Playground.this.Preference[_]]Playground.this.SocialWelfareFunction[Iterable[P],P]'s type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
type P's bounds <: Playground.this.Preference[_] are stricter than type _'s declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any
```

How can I write `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` , etc instances for contexts in which I am also using type parameters? Is it even possible? Is there a more appropriate way forward?

Comment: If `SocialWelfareFunction[C, ?]` is supposed to be a `Functor` in the second component, then it must have a `map` that accepts an `f: A => B` and maps `SocialWelfareFunction[C, A]` to `SocialWelfareFunction[C, B]`. Can you envision a `map`-implementation that can map a `Preference[_]` to `List[Int]` or `JsonNode` or `(Unit, Preference[_])` or `Either[String, Double]`? If not, then it's not a functor. Picking the types `A` & `B` carefully wouldn't help much, because many interesting constructions on functors and monads rely on the functor `F` being able to map `F[A]` to e.g. `F[Either[X, A]]`.

Comment: Perhaps what I really want to say is not that `P <: Preference[A]` but that `P` has an instance of the type class `Order[A]` defined.  Would this be possible?

Comment: Here is an [example with typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725356/how-to-implement-functordataset/48726850#48726850) (there, an `Encoder[A]` was required instead of an `Order[A]`, but it's somewhat similar). Actually, it should be possible in a similar way to get a "functor" for type constructors that have bounds on parameters. I'll sketch a proposal (will prob. take a few minutes).

Comment: I have a general demo of how to define `Functor` instances for type constructors that have type bounds and depend on typeclasses, but I still don't understand what you wanted to achieve there with that `SocialWelfareFunction`. It seems that you wanted to define a functor `F[P] = (Iterable[P] => P)`, which is impossible (because `P` is both an input and output, which makes it very similar to `Endomorphisms[P]`, which is also not a functor, regardless of type system or language).

Comment: I am learning FP by building a library for auction simulation.  It is very possible that my `SocialWelfareFunction` is simply not a functor.  Perhaps I can find a better example to demonstrate the interaction between type parameter bounds (or  type class bounds) when creating functors which is the focus of this question.

Comment: Can you post your demo? Perhaps seeing the demo can help me iterate the question in a better direction...

Comment: @davidpugh Posted the generic solution for "almost functors" with upper type bounds and type classes. It's essentially the same as in the answer linked previously. I think I will convert it into a "canonical" Q&A-pair to which I can link later, because this question seems to come up repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

**(Not a full solution, just a hint requested by OP to further clarify the question)**

This example shows how to define `Functor` instances for type constructors that look almost as if they could be functors, but have several restrictions:

1. Upper type bound `<: UB` on type parameter
2. Require instances of typeclass `TC`

Here is a way around these two restrictions:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

// Your favorite flavour of `Functor`,
// e.g. from `scalaz` or `cats`
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](x: F[A], f: A => B): F[B]
}

// an upper bound
trait UB

// a typeclass
trait TC[X]


// A type constructor that is not a 
// functor, because it imposes upper bounds
// on the parameter, and because it requires
// a typeclass `TC` for `X`.
class Foo[X <: UB : TC] {
  def map[Y <: UB : TC](f: X => Y): Foo[Y] = ??? /* 
    some very clever implementation making use of `UB` and `TC`
  */
}

// A Functor that approximates `Foo[X]` for *arbitrary* `X`,
// without any restrictions.
abstract class WrappedFoo[X] { outer =>
  type Base <: UB
  val base: Foo[Base]

  protected val path: Base => X

  def map[Y](f: X => Y): WrappedFoo[Y] = new WrappedFoo[Y] {
    type Base = outer.Base
    val base = outer.base
    val path: Base => Y = outer.path andThen f
  }

  def unwrap[Y <: UB](
    implicit
    xIsY: X =:= Y,
    yTC: TC[Y]
  ): Foo[Y] = base.map(outer.path andThen xIsY)
}

// Functor instance for `WrappedFoo`
object WrappedFooFunctor extends Functor[WrappedFoo] {
  def map[A, B](x: WrappedFoo[A], f: A => B): WrappedFoo[B] = {
    x map f
  }
  def wrap[A <: UB](foo: Foo[A]): WrappedFoo[A] = new WrappedFoo[A] {
    type Base = A
    val base = foo
    val path = identity[A]
  }
}

object Example {

  // two "good" classes that conform to 
  // the upper bound and have instances
  // of the typeclass
  class Good1 extends UB
  class Good2(i: Int) extends UB

  implicit object Good1TC extends TC[Good1]
  implicit object Good2TC extends TC[Good2]

  val x1 = new Foo[Good1]       // start with "Foo[Good1]"
  val f: Good1 => Int = _.toString.length
  val g: Int => Good2 = i => new Good2(i)

  // Now we would like to go like this:
  // 
  //   Foo[Good1] ---f---> Foo[Int] ---g---> Foo[Good2]
  // 
  // The problem is: `Int` does not conform to `UB`,
  // and has no `TC` instance.

  // Solution:
  val x1w = WrappedFooFunctor.wrap(x1)
  val intermediate = x1w.map(f) // approximates "Foo[Int]"
  val x2w = intermediate.map(g) // wraps "Foo[Good2]"
  val x2 = x2w.unwrap           // only "Foo[Good2]"
}
```